# Blackberry 10 Speech to Text on phone

Tags: blackberry, speech-recognition, blackberry-10, speech-to-text

Is anyone aware of any Blackberry 10 Speech to Text libraries that can use a predefined word (grammar) list and do their processing entirely on the phone?  I have a client that doesn't want to use their data plan (and in some cases wont have internet connectivity) for processing speech to text, but is really only interested in using a handful of key words to perform certain actions in their application.

Comment: Overall, qustions to recommend a tool are not welcome here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. You can easily use CMUSphinx  http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net on Blackberry just like any C library.

Comment: Sorry ... my intention was not to ask for product recommendtions (I'll do my own vetting of the products) ... but rather just to ask for knowledge about what products exist to do this.  I searched for quite some time and only found products that needed an online connection ... which didnt meet my needs.